# Site can't be reached when im using service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Hello there guys im new to this technology and i would like to ask for help for my code. What im trying to do is to cache assets files and have returned from service worker.

This is the code im using to register the service worker

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js')
.then(function(reg) {
// registration worked
console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
}).catch(function(error) {
// registration failed
console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
});
}
```

And this is the code inside service worker

```
importScripts('/cache-poli.js');

var CACHE_VERSION = 'app-v2';
var CACHE_FILES = [
'/',
    '/js/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    '/js/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js',
    '/js/plugins/prettyphoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js',
    '/js/plugins/jquery.sticky.min.js',
    '/js/plugins/jquery.easing.min.js',
    '/js/plugins/animate/js/animate.js',
    '/js/jquery.fancybox.js',
    '/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.1.min.js',
    '/js/jquery.scrollbar.min.js',
    '/js/plugins/owlcarousel2/owl.carousel.min.js',
    '/js/plugins/elevateZoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js',
    '/js/theme.js',
    '/js/cmsfuncs.js',
    '/js/theme-config.js',
    '/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js',
    '/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js',
    '/js/jquery.cookie.js',

    '/js/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    '/fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
    '/fonts/webfont/css/simple-line-icons.css',
    '/fonts/elegantfont/css/elegantfont.css',
    '/js/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css',
    '/js/plugins/owlcarousel2/assets/owl.carousel.min.css',
    '/js/plugins/prettyphoto/css/prettyPhoto.css',
    '/js/plugins/animate/css/animate.css',
    '/s/plugins/accordion/css/magicaccordion.css',
    '/css/jquery.scrollbar.css',
    '/css/megamenu.css',
    '/css/theme.css',
    '/css/slider/slide.css',
    '/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css',
    '/css/responsive.css',
    '/css/theme.css'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_VERSION)
        .then(function (cache) {
            console.log('Opened cache');
            return cache.addAll(CACHE_FILES);
        })
);
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keys){
        return Promise.all(keys.map(function(key, i){
            if(key !== CACHE_VERSION){
                return caches.delete(keys[i]);
            }
        }))
    })
)
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
event.respondWith(
    caches.open(CACHE_VERSION).then(function(cache){
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    })
)
});
```

Im using google chrome dev tools to see the installation proccess everything is cached as it should and the service worker shows no errors but when im trying to access the website again it gives me an error.

This site can’t be reached
The webpage at domain.com might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same error.

Actually, the problem is quite self-explanatory. What the browser is telling is that the path you are trying to reach is not reachable.

In your code, it looks like you have cached the root `'/'`. I assume you were facing this problem when you were trying to access some other path like `'/somepath'`.
Because you haven't cached those , you were getting this error.

So in your array if you also add :

```
var CACHE_FILES = ['/',
                   '/somepath', ...];
```

The error won't occur.

I used the exact same method and the error was gone.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I've already cached all of the routes that I'm using. Whenever I do Ctrl + F5 to refresh the cache, it works but if I refresh normally it doesn't.